# Does frequently changing the amount of power to a bldc motor wear it out?

Tags: brushless-motors

If you had a brushless dc motor and kept it running but changing the power input every few seconds/minutes would it wear it out?

I ask because for a drone like aircraft I'm designing, making turns requires change in rpm and input power. If it helps, the motors are large and 167kv bldc motor with 100cc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, changes in speed should have little effect. The only wearing part of a brushless motor is the bearings, which are generally rated for a certain number of rotations and a certain load (and are reasonably easy to replace).

With IC engines there are complex issues piston and bore temperature, expansion, lubrication and heat cycling - but electric motors are much simpler.